# Block insertions on a mysql table with specific value

Tags: mysql, insert, blocking

I've got a simple question:
I was wondering if it is possible to (temporary or permanent if possible) block the insertion of a record into a table with a specific value for a specific column. I'm using mysql with InnoDB

So I have this table Cart, which contains some columns and one of them is CartID (it is not the primary key thou). And I would like to block insertions in the table Cart with a specific CartID (let's say 100), while I'm doing work on another table in the DB.

Comment: Yes I would like to kill it completely (i know block is not the correct word since it is used in DB world as something different). Basically when I try to add something with the ID 100, it should reject the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful approach is to wrap all the basic operations like `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `SELECT` into the set of the stored routines. That acts like an API to the database and can be extended by any desired checkouts/conversions/calculations you ever want. If parameters passed to the stored routine meet some conditions you can `INSERT` them. Otherwise you reject those data without inserting.

Same effect can be achieved by trigger `BEFORE INSERT` that look like this:

```
BEGIN
  IF NEW.id IN (100, 200, 300, 456)
    THEN SET NEW.id = 1;
  END IF;
END
```

where id=1 is already existent record and `id` column have `UNIQUE` constraint. But triggers in general are unclear and non-transparent tool that can be very difficult to debug. Also autoincrements and triggers can interfere with unforeseen consequencies so it's better to avoid triggers as possible.

Comment: But can I dynamically update those stored routines? Because if I decide in my program suddenly that cartID should temporarily not be allowed, can I force it?

Comment: @Bosiwow Yes, SRs can be updated on the fly. Even better, SR can fetch blocked IDs from the separate table, that can be managed with plain inserts/deletes.